# Why is the conversion from EST to PDT in JSP wrong?

Tags: java, jsp

My code:

```
<c:set var = "redirectEnd" value = "September 19, 2019 5:00:00 PM EST" />

<fmt:parseDate value = "${redirectEnd}" var = "parsedEndDate" type="both" dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long" />

<c:out value ="Parsed date = ${parsedEndDate}"/>
```

This should ideally print:

```
Parsed date = Thu Sep 19 14:00:00 PDT 2019
```

But prints:

```
Parsed date = Thu Sep 19 15:00:00 PDT 2019
```

Comment: `September 19, 2019` is EDT, not EST, at least in the `America/New_York` time zone generally used by eastern US.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that was the mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Pay attention to the details.

EST has a timezone offset of -0500 (5 hours and zero minutes).
EDT has a timezone offset of -0400 (4 hours and zero minutes).
PST has a timezone offset of -0800 (8 hours and zero minutes).
PDT has a timezone offset of -0700 (7 hours and zero minutes).

You are translating from EST (-0500) to PDT (-0700).
That is a shift of two hours.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me and was suggested by Andreas!

```
<c:set var = "redirectEnd" value = "September 19, 2019 5:00:00 PM EDT" />

<fmt:parseDate value = "${redirectEnd}" var = "parsedEndDate" type="both" 
                                   dateStyle="long" timeStyle="long" />

<c:out value ="Parsed date = ${parsedEndDate}"/>
```

Changed `EST` to `EDT`